# Liliana - Corrupt's destroy order

Tags: magic-the-gathering-puzzle-quest

Liliana's Corrupt ability makes you "discard the last 2 cards in your hand".

If you do this to destroy 2 creatures and then Dark Petition or similar: "The last creature you controlled that died is Returned to your battlefield", which gets returned, the top or bottom one in your hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cards get destroyed from the bottom up, so the last card to get destroyed is the 2nd from the bottom, so the one on top gets returned.